# what is the mystery of Christ in Colossians 4:3?

Tags: colossians

Colossians 4:3 (KJV)

> Withal praying also for us, that God would open unto us a door of utterance, to speak the mystery of Christ, for which I am also in bonds:

What was the mystery of Christ that the apostle was referring to in the above text?

Comment: To whom God was pleased to make known what is the riches of the glory of this mystery among the Gentiles, which is Christ in you, the hope of glory.—Colossians 1:27. - The mystery is the indwelling of Christ's spirit (the Holy Spirit) in the believer, which includes Gentiles.